# Use raster calculator for fuzzy triangular function to fuzzify maps

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, fuzzy-logic, euclidean

Does anyone have an idea how to use the raster calculator to fuzzify maps with respect to the fuzzy triangular function?

I am using ArcGIS Pro. I am a little stuck after using Euclidean distance as I don't know how to incorporate the formulas in general to fuzzify my maps. These are for continuous criteria maps.